# Is there a way to use if condition and todays date in the same expression

Tags: ssis

Need help translating this excel expression in to ssis:
=IF(BA2="BAD",(TODAY()-BB2),0)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming derived column:

```
BA2=="BAD" ? (DT_DBDate)dateadd(day,-BB2,getdate()) : null(DT_DBDate)
```

This assumes you are subtracting a number of days. And I have no idea what 0 means in the false value. I chose null.